# Multithreading in Python throws HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

While trying to execute a simple code without multithreading works fine:

```
 q=Queue.Queue()
   def run_job(input,url):
        try:
            passman=urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
            # this creates a password manager
            passman.add_password(None, request_url, username, password)
            # because we have put None at the start it will always
            # use this username/password combination for  urls
            # for which URL is a super-url
            authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
            # create the AuthHandler
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
            urllib2.install_opener(opener)
            # All calls to urllib2.urlopen will now use our handler
            # Make sure not to include the protocol in with the URL, or
            # HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm will be very confused.
            # You must (of course) use it when fetching the page though.
            print >>sys.stderr, "Sending request: "+request_url
            # authentication is now handled automatically for us`enter code here`
            request=urllib2.Request(request_url, urllib.urlencode(post_parameters))
            pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            data=pagehandle.read().decode('utf8')
            q.put(data.encode('utf8')
   if __name__ == "__main__":
        infile=(codecs.getreader('utf-8'))(sys.stdin)
        while(1):
                 start1 = datetime.datetime.now()
                 t1=threading.Thread(target=run_job,args(doc,'http://example.com'))
                 t1.start()
                 start2 = datetime.datetime.now()
                 t2=threading.Thread(target=run_job,args=(doc,'http//example.com'))
                 t2.start()
                 start3 = datetime.datetime.now()
                 t3=threading.Thread(target=run_job,args=(doc,'http//example.com'))
                 t1.join()
                 end1 = datetime.datetime.now()
                 t2.join()
                 end2 = datetime.datetime.now()
                 t3.join()
                 end3=datetime.datetime.now()
```

But while making use of **`multithreading throws the error`** :

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required for the line 
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

example.com is a fake url, original link is our own machine link which i cant disclose.
I didn't understand why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited can you please check

Comment: Can you give us the multithreading code as well?